# Unable to get Parent Id from dynamic list

Tags: jquery

When I click on any select element it is returning select id not the parent id. What i'm doing wrong ? I need the parent id to manipulate select element

```js
var index = $("#olcityList li").length;
var $li = $('li.list');

$('#plus').click(function() {
  index = index + 1;

  $('li.list').last().after($li.clone());

  $(this).attr('id', 'listId_' + (index)).attr('class', ' ');
  $('li.list div.city select').last().attr('id', 'cityList_' + (index));
  $('li.list div.esta select').last().attr('id', 'estaList_' + (index));

  // Get the select id and its parent id 
  $('body').on('click', 'select', function() {
    $('#olcityList li:last').attr('id', 'listId_' + (index));

    var appendedlistId = $('li.list').last().attr('id');
    

    console.log("Parent id:" + $('select').closest('li').attr('id'));
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input id="plus" type="button">
  <input id="minus" type="button">
  <input id="getEachId" type="button">
</div>
<ol id="olcityList">
  <li class="list" id="listId_1">
    <div class="city">
      <select id="cityList_1"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="esta">
      <select id="estaList_2"></select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

As of now it returns parent id same as select id 
and the parent id for li:first element is always the li:element appended

Comment: Looks like event delegation issue, can you put only relevant code here and not the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating elements properly and also move the event handler outside the `#plus` button click event handler.

When you want to `clone()` a DOM fragment, get a reference to clone element and then perform all the operation on it. For Example following statement will actually manipulate DOM rather than clone object.

```
$('li.list div.city select').last().attr('id', 'cityList_' + (index));
```

Apart from above you are always setting `ID` using `.attr('id', 'listId_' + (index));`

*Here is the code*

```js
var list = $("#olcityList");

//Create clone for initial element
var $li = $('li.list').clone();

$('#plus').click(function() {
  var index = list.find("li").length + 1;
  
  //Create clone to manipulate its elements
  var li = $li.clone();
  li.attr('id', 'listId' + index);
  li.find('.city select').attr('id', 'cityList_' + index);
  li.find('.esta select').attr('id', 'estaList_' + index);
  
  //Append
  list.append(li);
});

// Get the select id and its parent id 
list.on('click', 'select', function() {
  console.log("parent id: " + $(this).closest('li').attr('id'));
  console.log("Current id: " + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="plus" type="button"> +</button>
</div>
<ol id="olcityList">
  <li class="list" id="listId_1">
    <div class="city">
      <select id="cityList_1"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="esta">
      <select id="estaList_1"></select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This worked , I Now have a better understanding of dom manipulation